# Java8: Why a lambda expression could do a logical and(or) with boolean

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, operator-precedence

I see in `and` and `or` method of Predicate, the return type is Predicate, while in the return statement, there is a lambda expression doing logical and(or) with a boolean. So how the return statement is evaluate when the logical and(or) has one operand of Lamdba expression and another operand of boolean. Why is this valid ?

Below is code for `and` method of `java.util.function.Predicate`:

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
}
```

Comment: It returns a *Predicate*, not a boolean. The evaluation is deferred until the predicate is forced. However, `test(t)` is a *boolean* as is `other.test(t)` such that the lambda body (boolean && boolean -> boolean) is well typed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this statement:

```
return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
```

the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `->` operator, so the expression is parsed as if:

```
return (t) -> (test(t) && other.test(t));
```

Thus, this returns the lambda expression itself, which is the logical AND of this predicate's `test` method with the other predicate's `test` method.